# Text not show when write on images

Tags: html, css

I have two images, one on the left and one on the right. I am facing issues in writing text onto both images. 
I am pasting HTML code and CSS code. Please correct it.

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#text {
  z-index: 999999999;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="images/banner-img1.jpg" class="left">
  <p id="text"> jhcjdhdjshdjdhjd</p>
  <img src="images/banner-img2.jpg" class="right">
  <p id="text"> jgdhdgdhddhhsd</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Increase zindex and test

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. And your CSS refers to two elements that don't exist.

Comment: Or .left{position:relative}

Comment: Please correct my code

Comment: Devpro I did both. nothing works

Comment: Try searching Stack Overflow for "Text Overlay on Image". This has come up thousands of times before. Do your research before asking.

Comment: Make sure you set the image element set as relative positioned. Id must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your paragraphs refer to the same ID, but ID's must be unique. Try using a class here instead.

```
.text { 
   ...
}
```

and

```
<p class="text"> ... </p>
```

Also, you use `class="left"` and `class="right"` on your image tags, but these classes don't yet exist in your css code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a container for the image and make it’s position relative. (to get along with the rest of the page)
Place the image within the container.
Place the text immediately below the image within the container and make it’s position absolute (to overlay text on the image) and place it as you please.
Finally, add some CSS tricks to suit your needs.